# Rails controller: Is nested rendering of views possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rendering, render

I am doing the Lynda.com rails tutorial and they explain how to render another view than the default one using render('methodname').

However, I noticed this rendering is not "nested". For example, in the code below, localhost:3000/demo/index would generate the view in views/demo/hello.html.erb, while localhost:3000/demo/hello would render the text 'Hello there'.

Is there a way to have "nested" rendering, i.e. such that requesting demo/index would return 'Hello there' in this example?

(Also, some use cases for nested rendering would be nice. I am asking only out of curiosity.)

```
class DemoController < ApplicationController
  def index
     render ('hello')            
  end

  def hello
    render(:text => 'Hello there')
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you exactly mean by nested rendering.

**Scenario #1**

If you want action "index" to be triggered but template "hello.html.erb" to be shown, you can do

```
def index
  render :action => :hello
end
```

This will render the template `app/views/demos/hello.html.erb` (or other format if you want it to (i.e. specify it in the url)).

So `render :action => :hello` is just a shortcut.

You can also do `render :template => "hello.html.erb"` or `render :file => Rails.root.join("app/views/demos/hello.html.erb")` (sometimes useful).

**Scenario #2**

If you want to render that text, you can just call hello method inside index method

```
def index
  hello
end
```

If you don't want other stuff from hello action to be run you can separate it to other method, like so:

```
def render_hello
  render :text => "Hello world"
end

def index
  # some other stuff going on...
  render_hello
end

def hello
  # some other stuff going on...
  render_hello
end
```

You can not render twice in the same action.

Btw the url should not say `/demos/index` but just `/demos`.
Index is the default action for `resources` route (`resources :demos`).

Please select the scenario which suits you (so I can remove unnecessary text from this answer).

Answer (score 0):

You're currently trying to render in a controller, all rendering should be handled in the views in Rails.

So for your structure above, your DemoController should be located in a file at

app/controllers/demo_controller.rb

and the views that will be rendered will be in files located at:

app/views/demo/index.html.erb

and

app/views/demo/_hello.html.erb (The leading underscore on the file name _hello.html.erb indicates to Rails that this is a "partial" to be rendered inside another page)

Inside the index.html.erb file you would call a render to the hello.html.erb file.  Your resulting code should look like this:

demo_controller.rb

```
class DemoController < ApplicationController

  def index          
  end

end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= render 'demo/hello' %>
```

_hello.html.erb

```
<p>Hello there</p>
```